# How do I update a time displayed in C?

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to display the time, then wait for a period of time, then display the updated time. My code however prints the same time, without updating it.

this is my code so far:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

int main(){
time_t timer;
time(&timer);
struct tm* time;
time = localtime(&timer);

printf("%s", asctime(time));
fflush(stdout);

sleep(4); //my attempt at adjusting the time by 4 seconds

time = localtime(&timer); // "refreshing" the time?
printf("%s", asctime(time));

return(0);

}
```

and my output is:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./tester
Sat Feb 25 08:09:01 2012
Sat Feb 25 08:09:01 2012
```

ideally, i'd be using ctime(&timer) instead of localtime(&timer), but I'm just trying to adjust the time by 4 seconds for now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`localtime` just converts a (pointer to) `struct timep` to a `struct tm`, it doesn't check what time it is at all.

Just call  `time(&timer)` after the sleep if you want the new current time, *and don't give a local variable the same name as a library function you're using in that same block*.

(And you're missing two headers - `<stdio.h>` for `printf`, and `<unistd.h>` for `sleep` - make sure you enable warnings on your compiler.)

Comment: hi,
i tried calling time(&timer) after the sleep, but I get an error when i try to compile it, saying
    tester.c:21: error: called object ‘time’ is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
                time_t timer;
                time(&timer);
                struct tm* time_real;//time is function you can't use as variable
                time_real = localtime(&timer);
                printf("%s", asctime(time_real));
                sleep(4);
                time(&timer);//update to new time
                time_real = localtime(&timer); // convert seconds to time structure tm
                printf("%s", asctime(time_real));

return(0);
}
```

Comment: A description would be nice.